# Jquery Mobile: Turn off all JQM styles on an element dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have an element:

```
<td colspan="3" data-enhance="false">
    <select id="CandidatesListBox" size="9" onchange="MoveToGeocode()" style="width: 100%" class="candidatesList" data-role="none"></select>
</td>
```

I want this element to have no jQuery Mobile styles. The problem is that I fill this item dynamically, and jQuery mobile will ignore all `data-enhance="false"` tags then adding dynamic elements through javascript. JQuery Mobile will also transform the control, so jQuery that would work on the item (`.add()`, for example) will not. I need to make a dynamic element with no jQuery mobile styles or elements. Is this possible?

**Edit**

I have also tried to disable all selects from using JQM, but get the same issue:

```
$(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
    $.mobile.keepNative = "select"; /* jQuery Mobile 1.4 and higher */
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQM adds styles and render them when you specify the JQM css file. Once it is called and unless you override the CSS by your own applying styles for a particular element cannot be stopped. Because JQM itself wrapps our elements with their elements. So as a solution get the element and remove additional class names added by JQM from the element. Also you will need to remove wrapping elements too.